# Range based for and deque vs vector

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I have a class for which internally holds pointers to its own kind in a container as shown below:

```
class A
{
public:

    A(int x) : _data(x){}

    A ** begin()
    {
        return v.empty() ? nullptr : &v[0];
    }

    A ** end()
    {
        return v.empty() ? nullptr : &v[0] + v.size();
    }

    void Display()
    {
        cout << "Data = " << _data << endl;
    }

    vector<A *> v;

private:

    int _data;
};
```

Now I want to be able to use the range based for loop on the objects of A and thus have written member begin and end for the same. It works as expected. But if I try to replace the vector with a deque for the reason mentioned [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm), it crashes when trying to access the last element. If the way in which I have implemented the end() is incorrect, can someone please provide a correct one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike `std::vector`, `std::deque` doesn't guarantee that it stores its elements contiguously. So in general pointer arithmetic will not do the right thing. If you want to use a deque, instead of returning pointers into it, you should return iterators.

If you would actually have the deque as a public member then it might make sense to directly return `std::deque<A*>::iterator`:

```
std::deque<A*>::iterator begin()
{
    return v.begin();
}

std::deque<A*>::iterator end()
{
    return v.end();
}
```

However, it might (depending on your application) be better to have it as a private member and implementation detail, in which case it would also be better to have `A::iterator` which could just be a typedef for the iterator into the underlying container type, to avoid inappropriately exposing implementation detail:

```
typedef std::deque<A*>::iterator iterator;

iterator begin()
{
    return v.begin();
}

iterator end()
{
    return v.end();
}
```